# How can I store list of directory files using pure Red language?

Tags: directory, red

I am trying to store list of files from directory in variable (using **only** CLI, Red version: 0.6.3).

I tested couple of functions from ["Red by example"](http://www.red-by-example.org/#cat-f01) documentation, but all of them give me only an CLI output with list of elements from directory:

- [list-dir](http://www.red-by-example.org/#list-dir)
- [ls](http://www.red-by-example.org/#ls)
- [dir](http://www.red-by-example.org/#dir)

When I tried save it into variable, I've got an errors like:

```
>> var: list-dir %tests
    other-tests.red         README.md               poc-tests.red      
*** Script Error: var: needs a value
*** Where: var
*** Stack: 

>> files: ls tests
other-tests.red         README.md               poc-tests.red       
*** Script Error: files: needs a value
*** Where: files
*** Stack:  

>> other: dir %tests
other-tests.red         README.md               poc-tests.red       
*** Script Error: other: needs a value
*** Where: other
*** Stack:
```

I also found the [call](http://www.red-by-example.org/#call) method, which give me possibility to run external scripts (like shell scripts), and by that I can execute OS command `ls`:

```
>> filelist: ""
>> call/output "ls tests" filelist
>> print filelist
other-tests.red
poc-tests.red
README.md
```

But this solution is dependent on the operating system. For example in MS Windows `call/output "dir tests" filelist` will work.

**Can anyone tell me - is there another solution for that using pure Red code without executing external scripts?**

Maybe somewhere there are some `magic` functions from **Red System**, whose will give us that?

That's would be great to be independent of OS.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All that's required is a READ of the directory:

```
read %tests/
```

This will give you a block of FILE! values for the contents of the directory.

Comment: Wow, it works. Earlier I was trying to execute `read %tests`, but without `/` sign. Thanks to your advice I have whole problem resolved. Thanks!